# BigQuery executing only one query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query in the UI, but I get the error:

> Error: 6.1 - 0.0: Only one query can be executed at a time.

I don't think there is any other queries running, and this has lasted for a while now. Surely it can handle more than one query at a time?? How long will this be stuck? How can I turn bigquery off and on again :p

[image]

Comment: Could you share the query or better a print screen.

Comment: @Pentium10 screenshot added

Comment: huh, you have 140 columns in your select? What's on line 6?

Comment: please copy paste the full query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that the query string has been parsed as containing multiple queries.  Check that you do not have multiple top-level `SELECT` statements in the query text box.

From the specific message, I would guess your second query begins on or around line 6.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I want to check all conditions from another table and if I use where clause then I have to write 100 ANDs.  Please check query: SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  hits.page.pagePath AS Page
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([2535XXX.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -10, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
WHERE
  hits.page.pagePath = ALL (
  SELECT
    hits.page.pagePath
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([2535XXZ.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -10, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))));